# Copying files from one user to another in a single machine

Tags: users

How can I copy files or directories from one user to another user on the same machine via the commandline?

Suppose there is a file `test.txt` in the home directory of USER1. I need to copy that file to the home directory of USER2 on my machine. How can I do it via the commandline?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Assuming that you have `sudo` privileges  the following command will do.

```
sudo cp /home/USER1/FNAME /home/USER2/FNAME && sudo chown USER2:USER2 /home/USER2/FNAME
```

Will copy the file from USER1 to USER2, and then change the owner of the copy in /home/USER2 to USER2

If you do not have `sudo` privileges, then the two users will need to ensure that you have read permissions on the USER1 directory, and write access on the USER2 directory.  If you have these accesses, you can enter the command:

```
cp /home/USER1/FNAME /home/USER2/FNAME
```

This will copy the file in question, but USER2 may not be able to manipulate the file until they have appropriate permissions.

Comment: The other option would be to set the permissions on their own folder to allow the other user to grab them, but this option is much easier if possible.

Comment: Does doing this use twice the amount of space on the hard disk?

Comment: @caffeinemachine Yes, as you are creating duplicates of the files in question.  You could use links for the second user, assuming that permissions in the first users directory have been set in such a manner that the second user has read (and write?) permissions on the file itself.  The manual pages (*man ln*) are a good place to start learning about links.

Comment: i get this error: "cp: omitting directory _______" oh I just realized I was copying a whole folder not a file, note 'sudo cp -r' and 'chown -R' to recursively copy all contents

Answer (score 18):

As USER1:

```
cp [filename] /tmp
chmod 777 /tmp/[filename]
```

As USER2:

```
cp /tmp/[filename] .
```

As USER1:

```
rm /tmp/[filename]
```

Comment: You deserver more upvotes :)

Answer (score 9):

If you don't have `sudo` privileges, an alternative may be to use `scp` with `localhost`:

```
scp file1 user2@localhost:/home/user2/
```

This assumes:

- You have the login information for both users
- An SSH server is enabled on the host
- can login via ssh

Comment: What makes you think that this is about a remote host or that there's an SSH/SFTP server running on the machine in question?

Comment: Assuming you have SSH installed

Answer (score 2):

Assume you either do not have ssh installed, or cannot do do not want to share keys/secrets.

Suppose user1 is in group1, and user2 is in group2, and both user1 != user2 and group1 != group2.

Create a shared group, group3s.

```
addgrp group3
```

Add both user1 and user2 to group3s.

Create a directory in a mutually accessible place, where one user owns, but has group ownership of group3s.

```
#as user1,
mkdir $place/shared && chown user1.group3s $place/shared && chmod 770 $place/shared;
#as user1 or user2,
cp $file $place/shared && chgrp $place/shared/$file && chmod 660 $place/shared/$file
```

But, suppose you cannot create the new, shared group, and place both users in that group?

Create the directory and give it 770 permissions,

```
mkdir $place/shared && chown user1.group1 $place/shared && chmod 770 $place/shared;
```

Then, as root/admin, change the group ownership to the other user's group,

```
sudo bash
chgrp group2 $place/shared && chmod g+s $place/shared
```

The command chmod g+s sets the setgid bit so that files placed into the directory have the group ownership set to group2.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below commands to copy files

```
sudo cp /home/USER1/test.txt /home/USER2/test.txt 
sudo chown USER2:USER2 /home/USER2/test.txt
```

Use the below commands to copy directories

```
sudo cp -r /home/USER1/directory1 /home/USER2/directory1 
sudo chown -R USER2:USER2 /home/USER2/directory1
```

Answer (score 0):

Every other answer here requires root access, allows *any* user on the same machine to copy the file, or requires password sharing. Here is a method that does not:

Have `USER2` (let's call him Bob) run the following commands (you can replace `/tmp` with any directory that both users have permissions to write to, but `/tmp` is ideal because by default it is sticky, which prevents a malicious user from subverting this process. A directory owned by Bob that is world-readable also works):

```
[bob@computer ~]$ touch /tmp/test.txt
[bob@computer ~]$ chmod 622 /tmp/test.txt
```

This creates a file that is world-writable, but not readable.

Then have `USER1` (let's call her Alice) run (if you're paranoid, Alice can check the permissions first to make sure the file is owned by Bob):

```
[alice@computer ~]$ dd if="$HOME/test.txt" of=/tmp/test.txt
```

This overwrites the contents of `/tmp/test.txt`. If you want to check integrity of the file, Alice should also generate a hash of the file. For instance:

```
[alice@computer ~]$ openssl sha1 < "$HOME/test.txt" > /tmp/test.txt.sha1
```

You can instead digitally sign the file, or any other method of guaranteeing its integrity.

And finally Bob moves the file and takes ownership of it:

```
[bob@computer ~]$ mv /tmp/test.txt "$HOME" 
[bob@computer ~]$ chmod 600 "$HOME/test.txt"
```

And Bob can check the integrity if he likes. If so, he should check to make sure only Alice can write to `/tmp/test.txt`.

```
[bob@computer ~]$ diff /tmp/test/txt.sha1 <(openssl sha1 < "$HOME/test.txt")
```

If the file was copied correctly, this should display no output.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to place the file in a subdirectory where all users has read and **execute** rights.

It will not work in $HOME as it has file mode 700.

```
mkdir -m 755 share              # 755 might be default with umask
cd share                        # you have to cd
touch file
sudo -u user2 cp file ~user2/
```

Answer (score 0):

try **install**;

man install
-o, --owner=OWNER
-g, --group=GROUP

```
install -C -o ldap -g ldap /etc/letsencrypt/live/privkey.pem /etc/openldap/certs/tls/ldap_server.key
```

Comment: This answer seems to have nothing to do with the question.

Comment: instead of copying the file and authorizing it with chown, I shared it because it finished the job in one command

Answer (score -1):

Before going to copy one user to another you need to login as su user and then you use the command cp

```
sudo cp /home/shyam/Desktop/sparkhadoop_2.11-1.0.jar /home/hadoop/Desktop
```

Comment: This won't transfer the ownership to `USER2` but leave it as `root` though. -1

Comment: @DavidFoerster we are not transferring the ownership, we copy the file from one user to another user. using root user, we can transfer the file. OK